# Linkedin API v2 Cannot complete multipart video upload

Tags: linkedin-api

I am implementing LinkedIn multi-part video upload, and I am constantly getting HTTP 400 on final step to complete upload. So I successfully registered upload, and uploaded all chunks as well, but on final request to complete the upload it always fails with HTTP 400 with no error text.

**REQUEST**(I have shortened etags):

`{"headers":{"Authorization":"Bearer MINE_TOKEN","Content-type":"application\/json","Accept":"*\/*"},"body":{"completeMultipartUploadRequest":{"mediaArtifact":"urn:li:digitalmediaMediaArtifact:(urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C5605AQFNb8_dDqQmGQ,urn:li:digitalmediaMediaArtifactClass:uploadedVideo)","metadata":"","partUploadResponses":[{"headers":{"ETag":"\/ambry-video\/signedId\/AQHX-ok3ZVEXKbzXbbNc4.bin"},"httpStatusCode":200},{"headers":{"ETag":"\/ambry-video\/signedId\/AQHCRXYeFezDepnlaL9MT1c6ZEtTmbHLZW7l27uW3TB-7Hwp4fhPH3r_gisT7EE.bin"},"httpStatusCode":200},{"headers":{"ETag":"\/ambry-video\/signedId\/AQF6qeurhH4SRX73lH95H4hb8kuk2ewWEZG0M.bin"},"httpStatusCode":200},{"headers":{"ETag":"\/ambry-video\/signedId\/AQEEZ1TRc9-QWyjCwvNB0lA2E.bin"},"httpStatusCode":200},{"headers":{"ETag":"\/ambry-video\/signedId\/AQG0tdOtE.bin"},"httpStatusCode":200},{"headers":{"ETag":"\/ambry-video\/signedId\/AQHclPE.bin"},"httpStatusCode":200},{"headers":{"ETag":"\/ambry-video\/signedId\/ZaABdsrBYs.bin"},"httpStatusCode":200},{"headers":{"ETag":"\/ambry-video\/signedId\/AQGU7oDvN9ssN_w.bin"},"httpStatusCode":200}]}}}`

**RESPONSE**:

`HTTP\/2 400  returned for \"https:\/\/api.linkedin.com\/v2\/assets?action=completeMultiPartUpload\`

Only thing that I have noticed is empty `metadata` field in completing the upload, but I have received empty metadata on upload registration, and I have seen that it should be in response while registering upload, at least documentation states so -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/vector-asset-api#complete-multi-part-upload

Any help would be wellcome, and if you need some more info please let me know ! Thanks !